# SQL Function for Financial Day of the year

Tags: sql-server-2008

How to get the financial day of the year i.e., if i pass 2nd of april to the function, it should return 2. The financial year starts on 1st of April for every year.

Comment: Do you include weekends (US, Middle East?), exchange holidays or bank holidays?

Comment: This might not be relevant to your application, but don't forget this is also dependent on the country you are in.  For example, Australia's financial year is actually from 1 July to 30 June so the 2nd of April shouldn't return 2.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_year has more information about the different fiscal periods.

Comment: It should count from April 1 to March 31st of next year. Thats all. No need to exclude the holidays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiscal calendars are specific to the organization and, although rare, can change. The simplest solution is to create a table that outlines the Fiscal calendar. So, you can mimic this using a CTE but it is better to store it as a table.

```
With FiscalCalendarStarts As
    (
    Select 1 As FiscalPeriod
        , Cast('20120401' As DateTime) As StartDate
    Union All
    Select FiscalPeriod + 1
        , Case 
            When Month(StartDate) = 12 Then DateAdd(m, Month(StartDate) - 12 + 1, StartDate)
            Else DateAdd(m, 1, StartDate)
            End
    From FiscalCalendarStarts 
    Where FiscalPeriod < 12
    )
    , FiscalCalendar As
    (
    Select FiscalPeriod
        , StartDate
        , DateAdd(d, -1, DateAdd(m, 1, StartDate)) As EndDate
    From FiscalCalendarStarts
    )
Select *
From FiscalCalendar
Where @SomeDate Between StartDate And EndDate
```

**Edit**

To get the day count (which I admit I did not provide in the above solution), the trick is to determine the actual fiscal year start date based on the input date. To do that, you could do something like the following, which per your request, I've put into a function

```
Create Function dbo.FiscalDay ( @Input datetime )
Returns int
As

Begin 

Declare @StartDayMonth char(4);
Set @StartDayMonth = '0401';

Return  (
        Select DateDiff(d, FYStartDate, @Input) + 1
        From    (
                Select DateAdd(yyyy
                        , Case
                            When DatePart(dy, @Input) >= DatePart(dy, StartDate) Then 0
                            Else -1
                            End
                        , StartDate) As FYStartDate
                From    (
                        Select Cast( Cast(Year(@Input) As char(4)) 
                            + @StartDayMonth As datetime ) As StartDate
                        ) As S1
                ) As S
        )

End
```

I start with the stub of `0401` which represents the month and day of the start of the fiscal year. To that I prepend the passed date's year so I get something like `20120401` if a date in 2012 was passed. If `@Input` is later than 1-Apr, then we're in the new fiscal year for the year of the `@Input`. If `@Input` is earlier than 1-Apr, then we're in the fiscal year that start on 1-Apr of the previous year. Now that we have the fiscal start date, we can simply find the numbers of days between them and add 1 (otherwise 1-Apr will be seen as day 0 instead of day 1). Note that passing 31-Mar-2012 returns 366 instead of 365 since 2012 was a leap year.

Comment: thanks. can u give the code without that tables?? i need the daycount which starts on April 1 to March 31st of next year??

Comment: @Olivarsham - I updated my response to provide the fiscal day.

Answer (score 1):

@Olivarsham, The financial year in not common for every country. Some where it is Apr-mar, some where it is Jan-Dec. So It it is your special application requirement then you need to write for your self. I think no standard query for that.

Kindly try this function. This will return your the day number of the fiscal year.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FiscalDay] (@CurrentDATE datetime)
RETURNS int

AS
BEGIN
     DECLARE @FiscalDay int;
     DECLARE @YearStartDate DateTime;
     Set @YearStartDate=Cast('20120401' As DateTime) 
     set @FiscalDay =  DATEDIFF(DAY,@YearStartDate , @CurrentDATE) 
     RETURN(@FiscalDay);
END;

GO
```

Comment: @Olivarsham Kindly try the given function